# -ms-text-size-adjust:auto not working on List in WebView

Tags: c#, css, webview, win-universal-app

Using `-ms-text-size-adjust:auto` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793579(v=vs.85).aspx)) to in instruct Windows Phone (running Windows 10 Mobile) to automatically adjust font size does not Work for lists.

This works fine and the text "Some Text" is automatically adjusted for the right font size on a Windows phone:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>html { -ms-text-size-adjust:auto;  }  body {background:white;color:black;font-family:'Segoe UI';font-size:14pt;margin:0;padding:0;display: block;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>Some Text
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work and "Some Text" in a list is not adjusted automatically on Windows Phone. For instance on a Lumia 950 the text is so small it is unreadable unless the user manually zoom in:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>html { -ms-text-size-adjust:auto;  }  body{background:white;color:black;font-family:'Segoe UI';font-size:14pt;margin:0;padding:0;display: block;}}
</style>
</head>
<body><ul><li><div>Some Text</div></li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the in-page style not having an effect on the text when the text is placed in a list? And what might be a work-around when changing anything but the css style is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this some more I ended up added this to the in-page style: `ol, ul { padding:0;}`. This did the trick.

The html now looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>html { -ms-text-size-adjust:auto;  }  ol, ul { padding:0;} body{background:white;color:black;font-family:'Segoe UI';font-size:14pt;margin:0;padding:0;display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body><ul><li><div>Some Text</div></li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this does fix the sizing issues, it removes the bullets or numbers from the ordered or unordered lists.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. Any suggestion on how to work-around this short-comming?